# how can I delete specific row data in my supplier table cause the error is when i use the order by it deleted all the supplier data in the database

Tags: php, mysql

how can I delete specific row data in my supplier table cause the error is when I use the order by it deleted all the supplier data in the database but when I use where it doesn't delete anything. what should I do thanks for your help

This is my Code for the delete button

```
<a href="supplier_delete.php" method = "post "onclick="return confirm('Are you 
sure you want to delete this data?')" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash text-
green" ></i></a>
```

This is my code for the supplier_delete.php

```
<?   php session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['id'])):
header('Location:../index.php');
endif;

include('../dist/includes/dbcon.php');

mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM supplier WHERE supplier_id")or 
die(mysqli_error($con));

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfully delete 
supplier details!');</script>";
echo "<script>document.location='supplier.php'</script>";  



     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your delete statement is missing the id of the supplier you are trying to delete. I like to build the proper sql statement seperately from

```
<?   php session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['id'])):
header('Location:../index.php');
endif;
$sup_id = $_SESSION['id'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM supplier WHERE supplier_id ='$sup_id'";
mysqli_query($con,$sql)or 
die(mysqli_error($con));

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfully delete 
supplier details!');</script>";
echo "<script>document.location='supplier.php'</script>";
```

Note that many mysql databases auto commit after sql statements are ran and if your sql is missing a parameter it might delete everything in that unfiltered scope. I had to learn this the hard way years ago.

Best of luck :)

Comment: Eldrikonis is thinking what $_SESSION['id'] is supplier ID. I'm not sure. Will be better if you publish a database row example here.

Comment: suppiler_id    supplier_name  supplier_address supplier_contact supplier_telephone supplier_fax
1              John Smith    3716 caellian    09353352198  854245  7874
2              Peter Wheel   3716 caellian   09353352198  84544    7554

Comment: Ok, you may delete the row (independent of number of columns) by DELETE command, you should explain MySQL which one (or more) rows you'd like to delete. Both answers show you the way. If you have an additional questions, do not hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass suppiler ID. For example, your table looks like below

```
suppiler_id    supplier name
1              John Smith
2              Peter Wheel
```

This way for John Smith

```
HTML FORM
<a href="supplier_delete.php?id=1" ....

SQL
DELETE FROM supplier WHERE supplier_id = 1
```

Comment: Of course, you may have number of columns, but other columns are not regarding your question. This is example only.